# Sql Query Need help

Tags: sql

Hi I need small query here are my tables

```
user table  

userid username

user001 987
user002 123
user003 456

logintrack  

usrid lastlogin

user001 7/22/2009
user001 7/23/2009
user002 7/24/2009
user001 7/25/2009
user003 7/26/2009
user002 7/25/2009
user001 7/26/2990


Expected Output    

userid username lastlogin

user001 987 7/26/2009
user002 123 7/25/2009
user003 456 7/26/2009
```

Regards,
Nagu

Comment: You forgot to post the SQL you are having problems with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure but hope it works, please try it

```
SELECT u.userid, u.username, max(lt.lastlogin) FROM
user u, logintrack lt
WHERE u.userid = lt.userid
GROUP BY u.userid, u.username
```

Answer (score 2):

lastlogin is not a good name for that column, as it is a list of ALL login dates not just the last one.